# Automate app pool recycling of an Azure Cloud Service Web Role

Tags: iis, powershell, scripting, azure, application-pools

How can I script (e.g. using PowerShell) the action to recycle the app pool of a web site hosted in a Web Role on Azure Cloud Services?

Only one instance of the cloud service is running (used for development). The reason for recycling is to work around a [Web Deploy bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/780597/the-stream-data-of-c-dev-solution-project-obj-dev-package-packagetmp-bin-project-dll-is-not-yet-available).

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not exactly sure of the AppPool name, you should be able to recycle an app pool with `appcmd`. For example:

```
appcmd recycle apppool /apppool.name: DefaultAppPool
```

You can also use PowerShell, by adding WebAdministration and executing [Restart-WebAppPool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790580.aspx). For example:

```
Restart-WebAppPool DefaultAppPool
```

How you execute this would be up to you. Maybe execute it via remote PowerShell. Maybe execute it based on a command you send your web role instance (maybe via queue message or some other technique).

Comment: It's the bit about remotely performing the command on a virtual machine sitting across a load balancer from me that seems the trickiest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the game, but can't you use [the recycleApp provider](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee522997.aspx) directly from msdeploy?